# Error when consume a web service "Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full"

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I have a web service that published on Glassfish server developed using JAVA 8 this web service is consume another web service published on the back-end.

The process on the back-end is processed successfully and returned a success reply, but my web service caused:

> Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full

Noting that I do not have any queue.

Comment: Please post the complete error message!

Comment: It's probably a problem in some setting or some code, we can only guess without more information describing what you are doing and what you have tried.